# Why can't I access a list by its key in Python?

Tags: python, list

I am creating a list, and then accessing an element like this:

```
list = []
list.insert(42, "foo") 
list.insert(43, "bar") 
list.insert(44, "baz")

print(list[43])
```

And I have the folowing error:

> print(list[43]) IndexError: list index out of range

What is wrong ? Do I have to use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to do this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no "keys" in a list, there are just indices.

The reason your code doesn't work the way you expect is that `list.insert(index, obj)` does not pad the list with "blank" entries when `index` is past the end of the list; it simply appends `obj` to the list.

You could use a dictionary for this:

```
In [14]: d = {}
In [15]: d[42] = "foo"
In [16]: d[43] = "bar"
In [17]: d[44] = "baz"
In [18]: print(d[43])
bar
```

Alternatively, you could pre-initialize your list with a sufficiently large number of entries:

```
In [19]: l = [None] * 50
In [20]: l[42] = "foo"
In [21]: l[43] = "bar"
In [22]: l[44] = "bar"
In [23]: print(l[43])
bar
```

P.S. I recommend that you don't call your variable `list` as it shadows the [`list()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) builtin.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because list[41] doesn't exist.

This will only work if list[41] is present, and in case it is the last element list.insert(42, "foo") is equivalent to list.append("foo"), 
else if list has lot more elements the values will be inserted in the middle

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood what [`list.insert(i, x)`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) does. It does not replace the element at the `i`th position, but insert the element at this position, **shifting the rest**. If the `i`th element does not exist, the element is inserted at the end of the list.

This example illustrated this:

```
list = []
list.insert(42, "foo") 
list.insert(43, "bar") 
list.insert(44, "baz")
list.insert(43, "qux") # qux is after baz, because baz in in fact at the index 2.
print(list)

list.insert(3, "test") # test is inserted between baz and qux, 
                       # because baz is at index 2 and qux at index 3.
print(list)
```

output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'test', 'qux']
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/Ykiqfdgc)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use a dictionary for this. A list always has consecutive indices starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you have the is a list of tuples, no key involved

print(list[1]) would have worked but, that ain't what you want to do.